# Rosbag migration: merging messages

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two message types being published on two different topics (pretty much synchronously), and I'm merging them into a single message--basically, adding one as a subtype of the other. I'd like to migrate old bags to this new arrangement, but I'm pretty sure the tools in `rosbag` are not capable of this. Is there a lower-level approach to migrating bags that might work? How can I access both the old and new message definitions in a Python script?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365258/rosbag-migration:-merging-messages/) by [JohnStechschulte](https://answers.ros.org/users/55404/johnstechschulte/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2020-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [python bag API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API#Python_API) is actually really easy to use. In your case something like this should work (not tested). I suppose the main question is how you want to synchronize the messages. Here I assume that the new topic should be publishes every time a new topic2 message has arrived and there was a topic1 message (anytime) before. This may not be exactly what you want, but I hope this will help you enough to get going.

```
import rosbag
from std_msgs.msg import Int32, String

inbag = rosbag.Bag('in.bag')
outbag = rosbag.Bag('out.bag', 'w')

try:
    parent = None;
    for topic, msg, t in inbag.read_messages(topics=['topic1', 'topic2']):
        if topic == 'topic1':
            parent = msg
        else:
            if parent != None:
                parent.sub = msg;          
                outbag.write('newtopic', parent)
finally:
    bag.close()
```

---

Originally posted by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) with karma: 553 on 2020-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JohnStechschulte](https://answers.ros.org/users/55404/johnstechschulte/) on 2020-11-10**:
Thanks--I've mostly just used ROS in C++, and so I basically didn't expect an out-of-date bagfile to open at all.

The only issue with your suggested solution is that you can't just assign to `parent.sub`, since the old message doesn't have the new `sub` attribute. So instead I imported the new message and created a new one, copying over all the other fields from the old message, and then inserting the sub-type.